# Left join with unique values

Tags: mysql

I am looking to get all values from first table along with joinned values from second table.

Table 1 is fee_category with fields:

```
id | Category
1  | A
2  | B
3  | C
4  | D
```

Table 2 is fee_charge with fields:

```
id | std_id | particularID | CategoryID | assign | amount
1  | 1      | 1            | 1          | 0      | 1000  
2  | 1      | 1            | 2          | 1      | 12000  
3  | 1      | 2            | 3          | 0      | 3000  
4  | 1      | 2            | 4          | 0      | 10  
5  | 2      | 1            | 2          | 0      | 100  
6  | 2      | 2            | 3          | 0      | 120
```

Base table is "fee_category" from which I need all values left joining with "fee_charge" from where I need values or NULL for a particular std_id and particularID

```
SELECT fee_category.id, fee_category.Category, fee_charge.std_id
, fee_charge.particularID, fee_charge.CategoryID, fee_charge.assign, fee_charge.amount FROM fee_category
LEFT join fee_charge on fee_category.id=fee_charge.CategoryID
where (fee_charge.std_id = 1 OR fee_charge.std_id IS NULL) 
AND (fee_charge.particularID = 1 OR fee_charge.particularID IS NULL) 
group By fee_category.id
order By fee_charge.assign DESC
```

Here I am trying to get all categories of std_id=1 and particularID=1

Correct result should be

```
id | Category | std_id | particularID | CategoryID | assign | amount
1  | A         | 1      | 1            | 1          | 0      | 1000
1  | B         | 1      | 1            | 2          | 1      | 12000
1  | C         | 1      | NULL         | NULL       | NULL   | NULL
1  | D         | 1      | NULL         | NULL       | NULL   | NULL
```

I am trying various versions of the above query but not getting proper result. Please help

Comment: There are a couple of things wrong here. Let's start with the GROUP BY, which has no place being in a query with no aggregate functions.

Comment: Is there an sqlfiddle?

Comment: Here is the sqlfiddle for this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ea334/3

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT fee_category.id
, fee_category.Category
, X.std_id
, X.particularID
, X.CategoryID
, X.assign
, X.amount
 FROM fee_category
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM fee_charge
     WHERE fee_charge.std_id = 1 
     AND fee_charge.particularID = 1) AS X 
     ON x.CategoryID = fee_category.id
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to follow when the fiddle doesn't match the question, so I may have misunderstood, but perhaps you're after something like this...

```
SELECT x.id
     , z.category
     , x.std_id
     , y.particularID
     , y.categoryID
     , y.assign
     , y.amount 
  FROM fee_charge x
  LEFT
  JOIN fee_charge y
    ON y.id = x.id
   AND y.particularID = 1
  JOIN fee_category z
    ON z.id = x.categoryID
 WHERE x.std_id = 1;
```